# Use angular-cdk table with bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm using the Angular [CDK table](https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview) (without Angular Material2) and want to use [bootstrap table design](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) to style it.

It is possible to add classes to the CDK table, but the bootsstrap rules directly address the html table elements `tr`, `td`, ... and Angular CDK uses custom tags `cdk-table`, `cdk-row`, `cdk-cell` ...

As quick and dirty solution, I wrote my own rules for the cdk elements with a lot of copy paste from the bootstrap sources.
But is there a nice and perhaps more future proof solution to automatically inherit the bootstrap rules for CDK tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had good results using sass version of bootstrap and adding the following styles for cdk-table:

```
.cdk-table { display: table; @extend table; }
.cdk-header-row { display: table-row; @extend thead; }
.cdk-header-cell { display: table-cell; @extend th; }
.cdk-row { display: table-row; @extend tr; }
.cdk-cell { display: table-cell; @extend td; }
.cdk-table.table-hover .cdk-row:hover { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a cdk table to use bootstrap 4 without any trouble. 
Assuming you have bootstrap installed, in the .component.scss file just add:

```
@import "~/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

You could also add it to the styles.scss file to make it global.

Then in the .component.html:

```html
<table [datasource]="someDatasource" cdk-table class="table table-bordered">
...
</table>
```

Comment: I think this is more correct than the accepted answer - cdk-table is supposed to be used as directive and not as element. It implements just the behaviour while styling is responsibility of the element to which it is applied.

Comment: perhaps this approach will work for the cdk-table directive but might come in short for the inner generated tags. So I would go with the accepted answer personally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. Cdk table isn't really a table element.

Comment: I guess what I recommend is not trying to make cdk table look like bs, instead write your own table component in bs style. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override style: .cdk-column-...name of column... { ... }. this is css class will be insert last in cdk-header-cell ...